# Android Facebook Login erorr in fb sdk3.0

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

When i login click on MyFblogin avtivity then i get

07-24 13:52:35.960: E/AndroidRuntime(28252): Caused by: com.facebook.FacebookException: Cannot call LoginActivity with a null calling package. This can occur if the launchMode of the caller is singleInstance.

how can we resolve this.

Comment: yes i have add fb library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your log shows the problem, change launchMode in your activity to singleTop

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            >
        </activity>